# Счетчик ссылок в python

Tags: python, memory-management

Вариант 1:

```
import sys
name=4.5555
name2=4.5555
print(sys.getrefcount(name))  # 5
```

Вариант 2:

```
import sys  
name=4.5555
name2=4.5555
name+=1
print(name2)
print(sys.getrefcount(name))  # 2
```

Почему в первом варианте счетчик ссылок равен 5 а во втором 2?
Неужели в первом варианте не создается новой переменной,а python ищет уже существующую и присваевает переменной ссылку на нее?
И получается во втором примере происходит как и в первом варианте,только выделение памяти под `name2` происходит при какой либо операции над этим объектом?

P.S. Дополнил второй вариант и попробовал увеличить обе переменные на 1,и посмотреть будет ли объект снова один для двух идентификаторов.Как оказалось-нет.Видимо такая штука работает при первой первом связывании идентификатора с объектом.

Comment: У меня в IPython в первом варианте выводит 3. CPython в обоих вариантах выводит 2.  `только выделение памяти под name2 происходит при какой либо операции над этим объектом` - есть такая штука: [copy-on-write](https://stackoverflow.com/a/628943/10941639), возможно (и скорее всего) это реализовано в Питоне.

Comment: Почему конкретно 5, не скажу, но хочу обратить внимание, что CPython выделит ссылку на только для переменной, но также для константы и аргумента функции getrefcount. Кроме того, дополнительные ссылки могут создаваться для нужд компиляции и интерактивной оболочки.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev ну почему конкретно 5 меня не интересует)Я понимаю что тут все завязано на реализации.

Comment: Лучше проверьте id обоих объектов ;)

Comment: Компилятор видит все константы и экономит на них место - все переменные указывают на одно место в памяти. А вот интерпретатор - уже как повезет.

Comment: Хотя возможно я не прав...